# OpenVZ wont create container error "invalid value for DISKINODES"

Tags: linux, containers, openvz

Please help I really have no idea why its not working, here is the logs

By the way, I'm using SolusVM as a VPS Manager. I did everything followed the given instructions but no work for me.

I also searched all over the internet to find the solutions but no hope at all :(

```
2012-01-22T02:32:02+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container config file does not exist
2012-01-22T02:32:32+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : WARNING: /etc/vz/conf/101.conf not found: No such file or directory
2012-01-22T02:32:32+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:32+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Destroying container private area: /vz/private/101
2012-01-22T02:32:32+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning: failed to remove /vz/root/101: No such file or directory
2012-01-22T02:32:32+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container private area was destroyed
2012-01-22T02:32:43+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/ve-basic.conf-sample:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:43+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Creating container private area (centos-5.0-x86)
2012-01-22T02:32:49+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:49+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container is not running
2012-01-22T02:32:49+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:49+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container is not running
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Performing postcreate actions
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container private area was created
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Restarting container
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Starting container ...
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container is mounted
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Setting CPU units: 1000
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Container start in progress...
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Adding IP address(es): 103.2.115.120
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : UB limits were set successfully
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : UB limits were set successfully
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Bad parameter for --diskspace: 21474836480K:21474836480K
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Unable to turn on second-level disk quota on a running container
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : WARNING: Some of the parameters could not be applied to a running container.
    Please consider using --setmode option
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Unable to apply new quota values: ugid quota not initialized
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : UB limits were set successfully
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Setting CPU limit: 400
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Setting CPU units: 10000
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Setting CPUs: 4
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : UB limits were set successfully
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : CT configuration saved to /etc/vz/conf/101.conf
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Restarting container
2012-01-22T02:32:56+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Stopping container ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
2012-01-22T02:32:54+0700 vzctl : CT 101 : Warning at /etc/vz/conf/101.conf:43: invalid value for DISKINODES ("20000000000:20000000000"), skipped
```

20.000.000.000, that's a rather high value for inodes, my best guess would be that your host does not even have that many available inodes to pass to containers. Start with a sain number like 300.000 and see if you can boot the VPS with that.